# Need help in scheduling in Java?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I pick up a schedule from a data source (file or dbms). This schedule tells me when to turn a device on and when to turn it off. eg 11am ON, 12:30pm OFF, 2PM ON, 3PM OFF...etc. This schedule is repeated on a daily basis. Each device has its own schedule.

I want to schedule all these devices according to their daily schedules. How can I do it in Java ?

```
public class Device{
  boolean state;//true is on.
  String schedule = "11am ON, 12:30pm OFF, 2PM ON, 3PM OFF...etc";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [**`java.util.TimerTask`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) and [**`java.util.Timer`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) classes.

You can use [**`Timer.schedule`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date%29) method to schedule a task to run at a specific time. Also from official doc:

> Schedules the specified task for execution at the specified time. If
>   the time is in the past, the task is scheduled for immediate
>   execution.

There are other variations of `schedule` using which you can schedule any task for repeated execution as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, Timer.schedule(argument) uses the deprecated Date class of Java. I don't think i should be using deprecated classes :(

Comment: @Time `Date` is not deprecated. What is the source of your information?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: As mentioned above, Date class is not Deprecated as such. It's those methods or constructors that deal with dates and time fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement a kind of polling pattern.... Make all your devices implement a common interface....

```
Interface DeviceScheduling
{   

    public String[] getOnTime();

    public String[] getOffTime();

    // task to be performed by device
    public void performTask();
    // stop device
    public void stopTask();
}
```

add all these devices to a `List<DeviceScheduling>` and then at specific intervals poll this list and check whether the current time matches or is lee than any of the entries returned by `getOnTime()` or `getOffTime()`. Depending on the matches call `performTask()` or `stopTask()`.